# removing unicode bullets with regex (python) - not finding bullet

Tags: python, regex, unicode

I searched around the forums a bit, attempted to remove bullets with every solution that seemed to apply.

"Fremont · Full Time"

Any idea on how I can slice the string to extract just "Fremont"?

I currently have this to remove bullets, but I get the following two errors:

```
string.replace('/\d\.\s+|[a-z]\)\s+|[A-Z]\.\s+|[IVX]+\.\s+/g', "")
```

This has no effect on changing the string at all, which tells me that the regex query doesn't recognize the tiny bullet

```
string.replace('/\d\.\s+|[a-z]\)\s+|•\s+|[A-Z]\.\s+|[IVX]+\.\s+/g', "")
```

This gives the following error:

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 20: ordinal not in range(128)

Also tried this way

```
bullet = u"\u2022"
string =u"Fremont · Full Time"
string2 = string.replace(bullet, "A")
newStr = re.sub(regex, "", string)
```

Had no effect

Any ideas?

Comment: Why was this voted down?

Comment: See my answer to the same problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39394437/python-regex-replacing-u2022/43214837#43214837

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This will do it**

```
import string
string_to_replace = "Fremont · Full Time"
regex = '\xc2\xb7'
string.replace(string_to_replace, regex, '')
```

**How I found this out**

```
>>> a = "Fremont · Full Time"
>>> a.split()
['Fremont', '\xc2\xb7', 'Full', 'Time']
>>> import string
>>> string.replace(a,'\xc2\xb7',"")
'Fremont  Full Time'
```

[edit]
As Joey correctly pointed out, this depends on the system's encoding. The `split` function should help figure out how a bullet is encoded in your system and the systems you expect the code to run on.

Comment: This depends on your system's encoding (which seems to be UTF-8 here), AFAIK.